# Dense ranking within groups that change order

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with many students, who each worked on multiple files, with multiple time measures on each file. I'm trying to produce a 'FileOrder' variable that indicates the order each student went through the files. I've been using dplyr because I'm comfortable with the verbs it uses. I've been able to make a sequence for each file that goes minute by minute, but I'm struggling to make a sequence for the completed files.

A few students and time points:

```
data <- structure(list(Day = c(67L, 67L, 67L, 71L, 74L, 74L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 68L, 68L, 68L), Hour = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Min = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 
19L, 35L, 36L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 54L, 55L, 56L), Student = c("C01", 
"C01", "C01", "C01", "C01", "C01", "C01", "C01", "C01", "C02", 
"C02", "C02", "C02", "C02", "C02", "C02", "C02", "C02", "C03", 
"C03", "C03", "C03", "C03", "C03", "C03", "C03", "C03"), File = c("capecod.ng3", 
"capecod.ng3", "capecod.ng3", "colonial.ng3", "colonial.ng3", 
"colonial.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "capecod.ng3", 
"capecod.ng3", "capecod.ng3", "colonial.ng3", "colonial.ng3", 
"colonial.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "capecod.ng3", 
"capecod.ng3", "capecod.ng3", "colonial.ng3", "colonial.ng3", 
"colonial.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3", "ranch.ng3")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), .Names = c("Day", 
"Hour", "Min", "Student", "File"))
```

Here's what I've tried, but the dense_rank() function seems to be ordering the files alphabetically rather than by time.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  arrange(Day, Hour, Min) %>%
  mutate(FileOrder = dense_rank(File))
```

Is there a call that will get me something like this (keeping in mind that there are multiple time points for each file which aren't shown here)?

**Updated desired output**

I would like a FileOrder number for every time point in each file. If I do something like @Adam suggested with `filter()` or `distinct()` which I'd tried before it only leaves one row for each file for each student. Ultimately I'd like to be able to select all of the time points for the first file the student worked on so making a variable where they are ordered seemed like a logical next step.

```
   Day Hour Min Student         File  FileOrder
1   67   10  13     C01  capecod.ng3  1
2   67   10  14     C01  capecod.ng3  1
3   67   10  15     C01  capecod.ng3  1
4   71    9  51     C01    ranch.ng3  2
5   71    9  52     C01    ranch.ng3  2
6   71    9  53     C01    ranch.ng3  2
7   71   10  19     C01 colonial.ng3  3
8   74   10  35     C01 colonial.ng3  3
9   74   10  36     C01 colonial.ng3  3
10  67   10  14     C02 colonial.ng3  1
11  67   10  15     C02 colonial.ng3  1
12  67   10  16     C02 colonial.ng3  1
13  71    9  12     C02    ranch.ng3  2
14  71    9  13     C02    ranch.ng3  2
15  71    9  14     C02    ranch.ng3  2
16  71   10   2     C02  capecod.ng3  3
17  71   10   3     C02  capecod.ng3  3
18  71   10   4     C02  capecod.ng3  3
...
```

*Notice that the sequence is grouped by Student and File, but the files are in a different order for each student based on Day, Hour, Min. With `dense_rank(File)` it wasn't respecting the different chronological order.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you just want the first file each student accessed, + the time stamps this file was accessed by the student in chronological order. In this case `dense_rank` is not required, neither is your example intermediate output table.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  arrange(Day, Hour, Min) %>%
  filter(File == File[[1]])
```

which gives

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: Student [3]

    Day  Hour   Min Student         File
  (int) (int) (int)   (chr)        (chr)
1    67    10    13     C01  capecod.ng3
2    67    10    14     C01  capecod.ng3
3    67    10    15     C01  capecod.ng3
4    67    10    14     C02 colonial.ng3
5    67    10    15     C02 colonial.ng3
6    67    10    16     C02 colonial.ng3
7    68    10    54     C03    ranch.ng3
8    68    10    55     C03    ranch.ng3
9    68    10    56     C03    ranch.ng3
```

If you do need the file ordering as specified for each file, then

```
data %>%
    group_by(Student) %>%
    arrange(Day, Hour, Min) %>%
    mutate(FileOrder = cumsum(File != dplyr::lag(File, 1, default = ''))) %>%
    data.frame
```

gives

```
   Day Hour Min Student         File FileOrder
1   67   10  13     C01  capecod.ng3         1
2   67   10  14     C01  capecod.ng3         1
3   67   10  15     C01  capecod.ng3         1
4   71    9  51     C01    ranch.ng3         2
5   71    9  52     C01    ranch.ng3         2
6   71    9  53     C01    ranch.ng3         2
7   71   10  19     C01 colonial.ng3         3
8   74   10  35     C01 colonial.ng3         3
9   74   10  36     C01 colonial.ng3         3
10  67   10  14     C02 colonial.ng3         1
11  67   10  15     C02 colonial.ng3         1
12  67   10  16     C02 colonial.ng3         1
13  71    9  12     C02    ranch.ng3         2
14  71    9  13     C02    ranch.ng3         2
15  71    9  14     C02    ranch.ng3         2
16  71   10   2     C02  capecod.ng3         3
17  71   10   3     C02  capecod.ng3         3
18  71   10   4     C02  capecod.ng3         3
19  68   10  54     C03    ranch.ng3         1
20  68   10  55     C03    ranch.ng3         1
21  68   10  56     C03    ranch.ng3         1
22  74   11   5     C03  capecod.ng3         2
23  74   11   6     C03  capecod.ng3         2
24  74   11   7     C03  capecod.ng3         2
25  75   10  45     C03 colonial.ng3         3
26  75   10  46     C03 colonial.ng3         3
27  75   10  47     C03 colonial.ng3         3
```

Comment: `dense_rank` allows me to save the order for the entire group. The output from this command puts the files in order but only has the FileOrder number for that single row. I would like to be able to choose the first file for each student later on. Is there a possible next step to apply that to all of the rows for the group?

Comment: doesn't my code reproduce the output example you gave?

Comment: to choose the first file later on you just need to do `data %>% filter(FileOrder == 1)`

Comment: I just made an edit to clarify the desired output. I have been able to produce a table with the first row only, but that isn't what I want. I want to leave all of the rows in the table, grouped by student and file in chronological order with a FileOrder column that indicates which was done first, second or third. The order changes between each student but `dense_rank(File)` seemed to be looking at the alphabetical order of File rather than the displayed order.

Comment: Please put your final desired output. I am extrapolating and trying to give you code for the final output here.

Comment: It is possible to produce the table you have given as an example, but it is not as straightfoward as producing what I think your desired output is.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use it in function calls to refer to the first file they worked on, for example: `table(data$Student, data$FileOrder)` to see the amount of time spent on each file, but primarily, for time series analysis on the first file that they worked on (with variables not in my example data):
`fit <- plm(Analysis ~ Construction, 
data = dplyr:filter(data, FileOrder == 1), model = "within", index = c(Student, Index)) # Index is the min-by-min sequence for the file`